# Maps SDK for iOS is disabled on my project yet google maps is working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

**I am setting API-KEY:**

```
// set google api key
GMSServices.provideAPIKey(Constants.googleMapsApiKey)
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(Constants.googleMapsApiKey)
```

**And do:**

> 1. GMSMapView
> 2. GMSGeocoder().reverseGeocodeCoordinate()
> 3. GMSPlacesClient.shared().fetchPlace()
> 4. GMSPlacesClient.shared().findAutocompletePredictions()

**Even that Maps SDK for iOS and Places API are not enabled!**

[image]

Comment: It's possible you are either using an API Key that belongs to a different project, or there is just some caching involved. So try to re-instantiate or reinstall the app. If those did not work, then I suggest that you contact the support so that they can investigate your project/API key further on https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Comment: I am sure its not that. Its something we dont understand